# How to create a plot with 4 conditions with different colors

Tags: python, pandas

I tried using

```
ax = pintar_campo('grey')

df_suarez.plot(kind='scatter', x='x<=17', y='y', color='light blue', ax=ax)
df_suarez.plot(kind='scatter', x='x>17 & x<=50', y='y', color='blue', ax=ax)
df_suarez.plot(kind='scatter', x='x>50 & x<=83', y='y', color='dark blue', ax=ax)
df_suarez.plot(kind='scatter', x='x>83', y='y', color='purple', ax=ax)

ax.set_title("Los eventos de Luís Suárez")
```

I have 4 zones and which zone have your condition:

- Zone 1: x <= 17
- Zone 2: x > 17 and x <=50
- Zone 3: x>50 and x <=83
- Zone 4: x>83

Comment: What is the result of your code? Does it return an error or is the output unexpected?

Comment: Return an error:  KeyError          Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:

8 frames
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'x<=17'

Comment: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 'x<=17'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the dataframe with your condition first.

```py
df.query('x<=17').plot(kind='scatter', x='x', y='y', color='red', ax=ax)
df.query('x>17& x<=50').plot(kind='scatter', x='x', y='y', color='blue', ax=ax)
df.query('x>50& x<=83').plot(kind='scatter', x='x', y='y', color='black', ax=ax)
df.query('x>83').plot(kind='scatter', x='x', y='y', color='purple', ax=ax)
# pr
df[df['x']<=17].plot(kind='scatter', x='x', y='y', color='red', ax=ax)
```